# Import scss from a secondary entry

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-library, ng-packagr

I have an Angular library which has secondary entries.
From one of those, I'd like to export a `.scss` file.

In my `.tsconfig`, I create a path:

```json
...
path:{
 "@my-entry/*":["my-entry/*"]
}
```

And the entry filestructure:

```
├── my-entry
    ├── index.ts
    ├── ng-package.json
    ├── src
        ├── index.ts
        ├── public_api.ts
        ├── */*.ts
        ├── my-styles.scss
```

In another entry, I'd like to `use` this `scss`file:

```scss
@use '@my-entry/src/my-styles.scss'
```

This obviously won't work, since I have only made a path for .ts, but I'd like to find a way to do something similar to `tsconfig -> path` for `scss` when making secondary entries.

Can this be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option called `stylePreprocessorOptions` for the angular workspace (Documentation found [here](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config)).

Add your path to the `build.options`:

```
// angular.json or project.json
"build": {
  "options": {
    ...
    "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
        "includePaths": ["my-entry/src"]
    },
    ...
  },
},
```

where `my-entry/src` is the path from the project root to the folder. You can then import your file (and other files from that folder or subfolders)

```
// your .scss file
@import "my-styles";
@import "subfolder/theme";
```

Since this is an angular configuration your IDE might not know that import.